# named routes with parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-4

I am building an authentication module for my application. I am now at the phase of activation. I send the link to user by email:

```
project/index.php/activate?email=$email?key=$key
```

so I created a route in my routes.php file to handle the activate but I don't know how to pass it the arguments email and key. Also will this route be get or post?

Comment: Where do you want to pass the arguments ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I am unable to construct it. I do not know how to create a named route with parameters.

Comment: I want to pass it from named route to controller MemberController function which is called activate($email,$key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MemberController extends BaseController {
    //...

    public function activate()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $key = Input::get('key');
    }
}
```

Route could be normally created without mentioning the query strings, you don't need to mention the query strings when creating the route, just add the query strings after the route, for example: `echo route('routename')?email=emailaddress&key=keyvalue`.

Comment: btw it is only getting one value that of the email and not the key. Any idea why?

Comment: How your link looks like after generating it ?

Comment: I get this output: someemail@gmail.com?key=2d105ce0edd99833e95a6a6382a920d78d8a5f633a2868dcd51f7978b454a409 AND array(0) { }.      After the AND it is empty where it should have printed the key instead of nothing. Instead it is printing the email and key as one string.

Comment: This is the link: http://localhost:8888/con/index.php/activate?email=someemail@gmail.com?key=dd51271bc2e83455b209e72bda723416527b88ebc2c712ef191fd2c18e1e7e2f